# Can we partition a table based on a timestamp column in GridDB?

Tags: database-optimization, griddb

In MySQL, it is possible to partition a table based on a timestamp column using the PARTITION BY RANGE clause in the CREATE TABLE statement. Can a similar approach be used in GridDB to partition a table based on a timestamp column? If so, how can this be achieved and what are some best practices to keep in mind?

For suppose we have a tables of orders which have 4 fields
1- id (unique auto increment ids for orders)
2- customer_id (id for customer)
3- total  (total amount of orders)
4- created_at (timestamp when order received)

```
CREATE TABLE orders (
  id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  customer_id INT NOT NULL,
  total DECIMAL(10, 2) NOT NULL,
  created_at TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  INDEX idx_customer_id (customer_id),
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
);
```

Now, I want to partition the table using created_at how can i achieve that in GridDB.